# Unable to parse string at a seemingly random position

Tags: python, pandas

I scraped a website in order to convert chart data to a dataframe format.

As such, all of the values of the graph are in the form of a String, which I am trying to convert to int form so it can be plotted.

The generated dataframe:

[image]

Since the values under Prime and Subprime headers are strings, I wrote the following to first **get rid of the percentage symbol** so I could subsequently convert the string to an int:

```
masked = df
masked.Prime = masked.Prime.str[:-1]
masked.Subprime = masked.Subprime.str[:-1]
```

This actually worked for the first dataset. But for the second one, I got the following error:

> ValueError: Unable to parse string "0.30%" at position 322

What's wrong here? I converted the half-parsed dataframe to Excel and it was successful up until that random position.

I've looked across this site for possible solutions, but I couldn't find anything that pertained to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try:

```
for col in ('Prime', 'Subprime'):
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col].str.strip().str.strip('%'))
```

Strip whitespace, then strip `%` values.